# What is the Possibility of A given B.

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

What is the Possibility of A given B, i.e.,  $\sigma(A|B)$ in possibility theory?

In [this book](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=524947), definition of possibility condition is explained, but honestly I can't understand it, could somebody explain it by an example?

> Let $(\Gamma, Z, \alpha)$ be a possibility space. Given $B$ occurring, we consider the possibility of $A$, i.e., $\sigma(A|B)$. Suppose $\sigma(B)$ and $\sigma(AB)$ are known. They represent possibilities of $B$ and $AB$, respectively. We note $B = (B - AB) \cup AB$ . If $\sigma(B) = \sigma(AB)$, then it can be  said that $B$ achieves its realization on $AB$. If $\sigma(B) > \sigma(AB)$, then it can be said that $B$ achieves its realization on $B - AB$
>   rather than on $AB$. So, given $B$ occurring, if $B$ achieves its realization on $AB$, then $A$ also occurs. In this way there should be $\sigma(A|B) = 1$. If $B$ achieves its realization on $B - AB$, then the occurrence of $B$ makes no difference on occurrence of $AB$. Thus $\sigma(A|B) = \sigma(AB|B) = \sigma(AB)$.
>
> **Definition 2.3.5** - Let $(\Gamma, Z, \alpha)$ be a possibility space and $A,B \in Z$. The possibility of $A$ conditional on $B$ is defined as
>
> $$\sigma(A|B)=\begin{cases} 
> 1,  & \text{if $\sigma(AB)=\sigma(B)$} \\
> \sigma(AB),  & \text{if $\sigma(AB)<\sigma(B)$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Here we note that in order to make $\sigma(\bar B|B) = 0$ , there should be $\sigma(B) = 0$.

Comment: I think you are looking for a definition, which [formally resembles](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Possibility_theory#Basic_Notions) that of conditional probability but relies on a "star" operation peculiar to your possibility theory, one which therefore cannot simply be multiplication as in the familiar definition of probability theory.

Comment: So in effect it is up to you to clarify your Question regarding the definition of "possibility theory" you have in mind.

Comment: @hardmath, could you look it again? I provide some more detail.

Comment: Note that your link is to a book, "Introduction to Fuzzy Reliability" by Cai (1996), and the definition of *conditional possibility* quoted is found on page 45 there.  This definition (**Definition 2.3.5**) is motivated by a discussion of "realization" of possibilities in the preceding paragraph.  A good survey of the early literature and alternate notions of conditional possibility is given by [de Cooman (1997)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.9640&rep=rep1&type=pdf).